# Inversely select with regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to strip a string of **all possible characters** apart from these certain words:

- red
- yellow
- green

[Here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bC69M/) The challenge is to make the alerts pop up saying 'red', 'yellow' and 'green', with rogue `x` and `p` characters stripped away. However, it still needs to strip out other rouge characters, indeed every single possible character apart from the words `red`, `yellow` or `green`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert( "xred-".replace(/.*(red|yellow|green).*/g, "$1") );
alert( "xyellowpp".replace(/.*(red|yellow|green).*/g, "$1") );
alert( "xgreenx".replace(/.*(red|yellow|green).*/g, "$1") );
```